# create table hive from txt with special characters

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql

Hil!

I have a txt with the following contents :

```
$ hdfs dfs -cat result/
[5,AA,ABE,US,AGU,MX,DNE0M0Z1,99991231,20160421,MX13,706,1,,33,,BOX,,,60,INNJ,31,2419221]
[5,AA,ABE,US,AGU,MX,DNE0M0Z1,99991231,20160421,MX13,706,1,,33,,BOX,,,60,INNJ,31,2419244]
[5,AA,ABE,US,AGU,MX,DNE0M0Z1,99991231,20160421,MX13,706,1,,33,,BOX,,,60,INNJ,31,2419319]
```

This file is generated by Spark in HDFS . What I want is to create a table HIVE read from that file and so to display the results in a table. The problem is that records begin and end by [ ] . As I can do this without changing the txt as it is automatically generated ?

Right now my table is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RESULT_LATAM;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RESULT_LATAM
(
  FARDET_NUM_RULE_TARIFF      BIGINT,
  FARDET_CD_CARRIER           VARCHAR(3),
  FARDET_CD_ORIGIN_CITY       VARCHAR(5),
  FARDET_CD_ORIGIN_COUNTRY    VARCHAR(2),
  FARDET_CD_DEST_CITY         VARCHAR(5),
  FARDET_CD_DEST_COUNTRY      VARCHAR(2),
  FARDET_CD_FARE_BASIS        VARCHAR(8),
  .
  .
  .
 )
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION '/user/ubuntu/result/';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to achieve this, but to demonstrate the solution I have used the less number of columns but you will get an idea. you have to develop custom `EDW` kind of solution where you load data in staging tables and perform transformation/clean up while loading in main tables:

**Sample Data:**

```
[5,A1]
[6,A2]
[7,A3]
```

**Create staging table**

```
create external table table_stg(x string,y string) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**Create main table**

```
create external table table_main(x int,y VARCHAR(10)) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**Load data in staging table**

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/cloudera/result.txt' INTO TABLE table_stg;

hive> select * from table_stg;
OK
[5  A1]
[6  A2]
[7  A3]
Time taken: 0.086 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

**Load clean data in main table**

```
insert into table table_main 
select regexp_replace(x, '\\[',''), regexp_replace(y, '\\]','')
from table_stg;
```

**Final output**

```
hive> select * from table_main;
OK
5   A1
6   A2
7   A3
Time taken: 0.155 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```